# iOS 7 safari possible javascript/dojo trim bug

Tags: javascript, ios, dojo, safari, ios7

Since the launch of iOS 7 we are getting orders through that have one character missing from the end of inputted data.

For example, if I enter `Tanveer b Bal` into the name field, it would return `Tanveer b Ba`. See screenshot below:

[image]

I believe the bug may be due to a `trim` filter we use on inputs to remove whitespace. We use the `dojo/_base/lang` `trim` function: https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/1.9/_base/lang.js#L510

```
String.prototype.trim ? function(str){ return str.trim(); } : function(str){ return str.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''); }
```

**Has anyone else experienced this issue?**

***Instructions to reproduce***

1. Visit http://demo.zoopcommerce.com
2. Add to cart
3. Checkout
4. Enter email address and name then click next
5. The email address *may* now be missing the last character

***UPDATE:***

I created a trim tester here: http://jsfiddle.net/QJFBL/embedded/result/ but it seems to work fine on iOS 7. (Created another one with more of my dependencies: http://jsfiddle.net/qmKvZ/8/)

I also tried my implementation on an iOS 7 VM on http://crossbrowsertesting.com/ and again, it worked.

***UPDATE 2:***
http://www.browserstack.com/ release an iOS7 VM today. I've tried my checkout with mixed results. Sometimes the bug happens and sometimes not. However, the bug still doesn't appear at all on a simple stripped back version http://jsfiddle.net/qmKvZ/9/embedded/result/, which makes me think there may be a deeper issue?

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` to the third clause of your ternary: `function(str){ return str.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');`

Comment: Thanks for that. It was actually just a bad copy and paste on my part. The code doesn't have that error. see: https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/1.9/_base/lang.js#L510

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't 100% confirm why this is happening on the iOS side, but I can confirm a fix.

From what I can tell (with a very limited ability to debug), when **autocomplete** displays over an input, it does not propagate the last `keypress` event. Since `dijit` only watches `keydown, keypress, paste, cut, input, compositionend` events, the last character of an input can sometimes be missed.

To fix this bug, amend this line: https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.9/form/_TextBoxMixin.js#L347 from:

```
this.own(on(this.textbox, "keydown, keypress, paste, cut, input, compositionend", lang.hitch(this, handleEvent)));
```

to

```
this.own(on(this.textbox, "keydown, keypress, keyup, paste, cut, input, compositionend", lang.hitch(this, handleEvent)));
```

Basically you are just adding the `keyup` event. Be sure **not** to handle it in a similar way it handles `keypress` and `keydown` eg. https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.9/form/_TextBoxMixin.js#L238

I will submit a bug fix / issue to the `dojo` team as well.

Comment: Have you filled a defect against dijit on this issue ? I would like to be sure it is fixed in an upcoming patch release. If you have the ticket #, please let me know and I will work on it. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same problem on a non-dojo app. It seems like something about the keypress / keydown/ keyup handlers changed in iOS7 because the code works in iOS6 but gets trimmed in iOS7

Comment: Yep. As I said, I think it's that the `keypress` event isn't propagated once autocomplete is triggered. A little annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely see the same problem with our dojo app. Removing trim:true from the data-dojo-props solves the problem, although this can only be a temporary solution.

Comment: I'm glad it's not only me, but I still haven't been able to fix the problem. I did create http://jsfiddle.net/QJFBL/embedded/result/ but it works fine in ios7 :S

Comment: Have you had any more luck with this?